# why cannot recursively call function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, long-polling

I am a newbie of JQuery. I want to recursively call 'pullNotification' function as long polling when calling the 'success' function, but my script is called 'pullNotification' function in two times when calling the requests from browser. So please guide me how to solve it. The following are my script. Thanks in advance.

```
jQuery(function($) {

    var data = [];

    function pullNotification() {
        var params = {};

        new RPC.Call({
            'method': 'users.getJsonUsers',
            'params': params,
            'onSuccess': success     
        });
    };

    function success(result) {
        if (data.length != 0)
        {
            for (var i = 0, item; item = result[i]; i++) {
                for (var k = 0; k < data.length; k++)
                {
                    if (item.userid == data[k])
                    {
                        this.found = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (this.found)
                {
                    this.data.push(item.userid);
                    $('<tr origclass="even_row" class="even_row">\n\\n\
                                    <td>' + item.userid + '</td>\n\
                                    <td>' + item.alias + '</td>\n\
                                    <td>' + item.surname + '</td>\n\
                                    </tr>').insertAfter('.nilar');
                }
                this.found = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            for (var j = 0; j < result.length; j++)
            {
                data.push(result[j].userid);
            }            
        }

        setTimeout(function() {
                pullNotification();
            }, 1000);
    }

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        pullNotification();
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only call pullNotification `onSuccess` -- is there an `onFailure`? It might be easier (and easier to reason about) if you did

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
  window.setInterval(function() {
    pullNotification();
  }, 1000);
}, 5000);
```

and then removed the `setTimeout` from `success(result) { ... }`

That way, you will call `pullNotification` once per second regardless of what's happening. It does have the potential to continue to ping your server if requests take longer than 1 second though.

Comment: That said, to remove the `setTimeout` function, one should first store the latter in a variable.

Comment: Now 'pullNotification' function is work but 'success(result) {..}' doesn't work. I am wrong write for 'onSuccess: success' in my script.